# Is my code triggering the N-Channel MOSFET as I have intended to

Tags: digital, mosfet

I have a certain bit of code that I believe after 10 seconds will send a high signal to the second digital pin for 50 seconds. After it will not do anything.

For some reason the nichrome wire is not heating up. I realize there could be a problem with my circuit but just want to make sure for the final time it is not an issue with my code. Thanks.

```
int nichromePin = 2; 


unsigned long burnTime = 10000;
unsigned long dt = 50000;
unsigned long time;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(nichromePin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Balloon Countdown...");
  Serial.print("When Will It Burn: ");
  Serial.println(burnTime);

}

void loop()
{
  time = millis();

  if (time > burnTime && time < burnTime+dt)
  {
  digitalWrite(nichromePin, HIGH);
  Serial.print("Time: ");
  Serial.println(time);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try simplifying.  Make dt = 60000 and then check if time is more than burntime and less than dt.

Answer (score 1):

The code is as follows: After 10 seconds following Arduino power up, burn the nichrome for 60 seconds, after which do nothing. I just tested it on my UNO and it works fine, so it must be your circuit. Post your nichrome question in the EE forums for help on that.

P.S. This code is kinda silly tho there's no trigger event!

Comment: And note that there's no code to turn the nichrome wire off again once you're done.